# Embed and extract a string in various file types with C#

Tags: c#, file, streaming

We are working on a digital market. users can buy file and download them. file types are pdf, mp3, mp4, jpg, apk(android app).

For some reasons, product owner wants files can be traceable which who downloaded this file. this means when a user wants to download a file we should embed UserId to file. And we should able to extract this userId from file later.

I heard about adding watermark to mp3 files but I'm looking for a general purpose solution for all file types or at least for pdf, mp3, mp4, jpg and apk.

Is there anyway to add a string to a file(any file type) and extract it from file later. this string shouldn't corrupt file and user shouldn't see it.

Comment: most filetypes, especially commercial ones usually have "tags" in the file header to write anything. but the tags are usually different between filetypes. But this is as much generic as anyone can get. Other than that you have to resolve to pretty much complicate solutions like the one you mentioned. Tags can be easily stripped of any information though

Comment: I think providing a solution for each file type is a little bit to much. I would recommend that you start searching on your own. The most popular file types are well documented some where...

Answer (score 1):

To find a general solution will be very hard/impossible, because every file type is different from one another. If it is possible for a format, you should write a kind of `FileTypeWatermarkProvider`, all the providers should then derives from a single interface. But in my point of view you can not get rid of writing single solutions. For example:

General provider:

```
public interface IFileWatermarkProvider
{
    void EmbeddUserId(int userId);
}
```

Formats:

```
public class PdfWatermarkProvider : IFileWatermarkProvider {}
public class MP3WatermarkProvider : IFileWatermarkProvider {}
public class ApkWatermarkProvider : IFileWatermarkProvider {}
```

I think this is the best soltuion. Where to store the information should be proofed for every file format.

Hope this helps a little bit...